# MVC 5 Scaffolding with inheritance uses the wrong entity set

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, dbcontext, entity-framework-6.1

With MVC 5 and EF 6.1 I am using a simple inheritance hierarchy, where class Student inherits from class Person. For both classes I have an entity set (DbSet property) in my database context:

```
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

Now when I ask the scaffolder to generate a controller for Student, the subclass, it uses the Persons entity set, leading to statements such as

```
    Student student = db.Persons.Find(id);
```

where the compiler obviously complains that it cannot just convert any Person to a Student.

Is there a way to make sure that the scaffolder uses the correct entity set (Students in this case)?

Note that removing the Persons entity set is not a good solution, because there are other controllers that need that.

Comment: Are you sure your inheritance code is correct?

Comment: Well, I guess the inheritance code is correct, because the diagram that EF PowerTools generates correctly shows the inheritance relationship.

Comment: Another observation: When I replace all occurrences of Persons by Students, the generated web interface functions correctly. Moreover, ASP.NET Dynamic Data (which does the scaffolding automatically) works correctly on the same EF model and database.

Answer (score 2):

Use find and replace to change all occurrences in the Controller class of the parent DBSet to the child DBSet eg change Persons to Students.

As you probably know (as I think you raised it) Microsoft have confirmed this is a known bug http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedbackdetail/view/945937/mvc-5-scaffolding-with-inheritance-uses-the-wrong-entity-set but they won't be fixing it.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of inheritance why not use a relationship making personID the  Foreign key ? That why you can db.students.find(personID)
And
db.person.find(personID)

To find all details ?
Extra code but I can't think of another way

Answer (score 1):

You can use the command OfType<>, as shown:

```
Student student = db.Persons.OfType<Student>().SingleOrDefault(s => s.id == id);
```

This command works with inheritance. In this case, when Student inherits from Person.